# Import Module in Python file

Tags: python-3.x, import, python-import

Project stucture:

```
API 
├── Models
│   └── PSU 
|       └── PSUInjector.py
└── Controller 
    └── PSUController.py
```

I want to import the class PSUInjector from the PSUInjector.py into the PSUController.py. I added an `__init__.py` to `/API`, `/Models` and `/PSU`.

I tried:

```py
from Models.PSU.PSUInjector import PSUInjector
```

But i get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Models'`. Using a relative import like `from ..Models.PSU.PSUInjector import PSUInjector` lead to `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`. I trying running it in the `/Controller` Directory using VS Code in a virtual environment.

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
from Models.PSU.PSUInjector import PSUInjector
```

That works but why do the others not work?

Comment: How do you run the code?

Comment: Have you tried `from API.Models... import ...`?

Comment: Seems to be invalid syntax

Comment: I mean not literally, but changing `Models` to `API.Models`.

Comment: Same error message just `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'API'`